# HTML Button not interacting with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm attempting to make a simple click counter. I believe my JS is sound, but I'm not getting any functionality from the HTML button calling it.

I've tried calling my JS function from the HTML button using..

```
 <button onclick="addOne()"
```

..but the button simply isn't producing an output. Below is a sample of the issue which features my JS function and HTML.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h1><span id="thisone">1</span></h1>
        <button onclick="addOne()" type="submit">Button</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addOne(){
        const foo = document.getElementById('thisone').innerHTML;
        foo++;
        document.getElementById('thisone').innerHTML = foo;    
    };
</script>
```

As of now, it simply presses and the number remains unchanged.
I'm trying to have the number in  increase by 1 each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason because your code doesn't work is in the doc:

> [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const): Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.

Would also recommend changing from 'onclick' to 'onClick'

```js
function addOne(){
    var foo = document.getElementById('thisone').innerHTML;
    foo++;
    document.getElementById('thisone').innerHTML = foo;
};
```

```html
<div>
    <h1><span id="thisone">1</span></h1>
    <button onClick="addOne()" type="submit">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`const` keyword declares a constant value and hence cannot be modified using the `++` operator. use the `let` keyword instead of `const` to allow modification of the `foo` variable.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem you must replace your `const` keyword with the `let` keyword. This is because `const` declares a block-scoped, read-only named constant. Meanwhile `let` declares a block-scoped, local variable, optionally initializing it to a value. In laymans terms use `const` if you are not going to update or change the variable and use `let` if you are going to update or change the variable.

P.S. Using the `var` keyword is a es5 keyword and is not recommended since es6 introduced the `let` keyword as well as the `const`.

You can see the code in action [here on codepen](https://codepen.io/JonDevOps/pen/jONrRNR)

HTML

```
<div>
    <h1><span id="thisone">1</span></h1>
    <button onclick="addOne()" type="submit">Button</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript(es6)

```
function addOne(){
    let foo = document.getElementById('thisone').innerHTML;
    foo++;
    document.getElementById('thisone').innerHTML = foo;
};
```

You can find more information about Javascript declarations here at [Mozilla Developer Network.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types)

[Const Declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) (es6)

[Let Declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) (es6)

[Var Declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) (es5)

MDN also has really nice [learning documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn)

Here is also a nice in article explaining [ES6 In Depth: Const and let](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-let-and-const/)

Answer (score 2):

Please put your script between the head tags or, at least, before the button.

Answer (score 2):

Replace const with let, since you are reassigning/ updating a new value for **foo**